# Flutter - Overriding "build" method of CupertinoTabBar

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm currently trying to customize the CupertinoTabBar widget by making my own class extend it and override the "build" method. My current code looks similar to this:

```
class CustomTabBar extends CupertinoTabBar {
  CustomTabBar(
    Key key,
    @required List<BottomNavigationBarItem> items,
    ValueChanged<int> onTap,
    int currentIndex = 0,
    Color backgroundColor = _kDefaultTabBarBackgroundColor,
    Color activeColor = CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
    Color inactiveColor = CupertinoColors.inactiveGray,
    double iconSize = 30.0,
  ) : assert(items != null),
      super(items: items, onTap: onTap, currentIndex: currentIndex, 
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor, activeColor: activeColor, 
        inactiveColor: inactiveColor, iconSize: iconSize);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //build logic for the custom bar
  }
}
```

However, when I run the app, the CupertinoTabBar build method is being called instead of the CustomTabBar build method. In other words, my class is not overriding CupertinoTabBar's build.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? The reason I'm doing it this way is because I'm using the CupertinoTabScaffold to keep separate Navigators for each tab and the tabBar parameter of CupertinoTabScaffold accepts only a CupertinoTabBar.

Comment: Could you paste code from your overriden method?

Answer (score 2):

You need to override **copyWith** method.

```
class CustomTabBar extends CupertinoTabBar {
  CustomTabBar(
    Key key,
    @required List<BottomNavigationBarItem> items,
    ValueChanged<int> onTap,
    int currentIndex = 0,
    Color backgroundColor = _kDefaultTabBarBackgroundColor,
    Color activeColor = CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
    Color inactiveColor = CupertinoColors.inactiveGray,
    double iconSize = 30.0,
  ) : assert(items != null),
      super(items: items, onTap: onTap, currentIndex: currentIndex, 
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor, activeColor: activeColor, 
        inactiveColor: inactiveColor, iconSize: iconSize);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //build logic for the custom bar
  }

  @override
  CustomTabBar copyWith({
    Key key,
    List<BottomNavigationBarItem> items,
    Color backgroundColor,
    Color activeColor,
    Color inactiveColor,
    Size iconSize,
    Border border,
    int currentIndex,
    ValueChanged<int> onTap,
  }) {
    return CustomTabBar(
      key: key ?? this.key,
      items: items ?? this.items,
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor ?? this.backgroundColor,
      activeColor: activeColor ?? this.activeColor,
      inactiveColor: inactiveColor ?? this.inactiveColor,
      iconSize: iconSize ?? this.iconSize,
      border: border ?? this.border,
      currentIndex: currentIndex ?? this.currentIndex,
      onTap: onTap ?? this.onTap
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why this only works when you override `copyWith` method?

Comment: @Hugo Passos maybe kinda late but it's because CupertinoTabScaffold use the copyWith function to assign `currentIndex` and their `onTap`  listener

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/9944297138845a94256f1cf37beb88ff9a8e811a/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/tab_scaffold.dart#L377